# LED for LCD laptops

Tags: laptop, display

Before my uncle went overseas, he pass on me a laptop that is also passed on him, making me the 3rd or > owner. Accidentally my sister stepped on the laptop causes its screen to crack. I phone the nearest spare-part dealer around, gave him the laptop model and ask if he has a replacement part for its screen. He said yes so we went to his shop for him to service my laptop.

When he was diagnosing the cracked screen, he said that he will refuse servicing my laptop because:

1. My model is registered as a laptop using a LCD screen, *but*
2. The current damage screen is LED, not LCD.

> He said *"this (the damaged screen) screen model was not supposed to be used on this laptop model because its LED, You first need to adjust these wires (points some of the wire), for screen models such as this (the damaged screen) to work for your laptop."*

I asked if he have an available 15 inches LED, he said yes, but still refuses to replace it. He told me to seek the original owner of the laptop and go there and ask the person who changed the laptop screen from LCD to LED, find the person and go ask him to service this laptop.

Of course I don't know who was the original owner. So I bought the available LED returned home and installed it myself. And now its working again.

My question is why are they afraid to service my laptop? Do LED screen suppose not to work on LCD screen? Is he afraid on *actually* damaging his spare-part? Installing the screen isn't that hard, I've manage to install it myself. And their jack and connector looked the same to me.

Comment: A “LED screen” is still LCD. It just uses LEDs instead of CCFLs to provide backlight.

Comment: There is no such thing as a LED screen. There are OLED and AMOLED screens, but they were never used in laptops, except for few prototypes that never reached the mass market. It would be easier to answer your question if we knew the laptop model.

Comment: @gronostaj Now I'm confused. I forgot the model but my Laptop is Acer (its not with me at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cracked screen all you can do is to replace it. And LED LCD is still LCD.

LED means that backlight for the screen is coming from LEDs, not old-style-CCFL.
For him or for laptop makes absolutely no difference from service point of view.
Except for maybe he's trying to sell you outdated part no one wants anymore.

Change your service supplier. And to replace the screen yourself... It's rather easy, as you found out.

EDIT: Oh, what laptop is this?

Comment: He said that the connections (maybe the wires) are flipped / tampered? He said _"this (the damaged screen) screen model was not supposed to be used on this laptop model because its LED, You first need to adjust these wires, for screen models, such as these (the damaged screen) to work for your laptop."_.

Comment: Its an ACER laptop by the way, forgot the model, it's not with me at the moment.

Comment: It's possible that the laptop had old-style connector and there was new screen inserted at some point. But highly doubtful, as this is very fine work, very difficult to do by hand...

Comment: And with "very fine work" I'm referring to rewiring the LVDS cable to fit new connector (which is flatter, smaller and there's one plug instead of two - second for power)...